# Maximum number of Google accounts using the same mobile number

Tags: google-account, account-recovery

I have created a few Google(Gmail) accounts for separate purposes. I often provide my primary Gmail account and my (only) mobile number as the recovery email and phone number.

My concern is that at some point Google may stop allowing me to use a specific phone/email combo as recovery contact.

Is there a hard limit (preferably documented) on the number of Google accounts that I can create using the same email/phone combo?

Comment: Related: [Google account recovery phone usage list and limits](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/109007/88163)

Comment: I was able to create my 5th account with the same number (as of May 2020), but the 6th one failed with the message that my number was already used too many times. So I would say that 5 seems to be the current limit. After the account was created (with another number), I was able to change the number to my own number though. Context: I use several Chrome profiles, according to what type of activity I'm doing on the browser (studying, working, gaming etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the purpose is solely be used for account recovery purposes, I don't think that there is a limit, by the other hand, the phone number used for account verification purposes certainly has a limit.

From [Verify your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/114129?hl=en)

> "This phone number cannot be used for verification"
>   If you see this error message, you'll have to use a different number. In an effort to protect you from abuse, we limit the number of accounts each phone number can create.

Usually Google doesn't reveal limits like this to avoid system abuse.